# Strange size in Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am facing a strange issue with Sprite Kit (on OS X, didn't tried it on iOS) : I create my scene with this code :

```
    SKScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 800)];
```

And when I create a node, like this :

```
    SKSpriteNode* ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[NSColor brownColor] size:CGSizeMake(1280, 800)];
```

What I don't understand is that even if I create my sprite with the same size than my scene, I get this :
[image]

As you an see, my sprite, in brown, is two times smaller than my scene (with the blue background).

**Do you know why ?**

Comment: BTW: If you're developing for iOS and Mac OSX, then use `SKColor` instead of `NSColor`.

Comment: @user867635 Thanks for this advice ! I had confused the two !

Comment: When I started with Sprite Kit, I was confused about that too. But `SKColor` is just a macro that resolves to `UIColor` on iOS and `NSColor` on OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add:

```
ground.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
```

or

```
ground.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2);
```

The `SKSpriteNode`'s anchor point is in the center (0.5,0.5) and the default `position` is `CGPointZero`. So you only see the top right part of your ground.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works ! BTW, why do I need to do that ? I thought that the default position of any sprite where (0;0) !?

Comment: You are right, but the anchor point is at (0.5, 0.5). I edited my answer with a more detailed explanation